# fprintf 0 gives unexpected results under windows MinGW

Tags: c, window, gtk, mingw, printf

I am currently porting a C project from linux to windows, during which I encounter a weird error. In the source file it has these two lines:

```
    fprintf(fp, "%4d %11.6f %11.6f %11.6f\n", cell->total_atom_no, 0, 0, 0);
    printf("%4d %11.6f %11.6f %11.6f\n", cell->total_atom_no, 0, 0, 0);
```

To be clear, the file is opened in binary mode "wb".
The output in the file is:

```
      18    0.000000    0.000000 166818935138251830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

While the output in the command line is:

```
      18    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

The command line version is correct.
But under linux both the file and command line will give the correct output. I cannot make a reproducable code as if I try a simple code:

```
    int a = 18;
    fprintf(fp, "%4d %11.6f %11.6f %11.6f\n", a, 0, 0, 0);
```

It will give the expected output. Neither can I upload the original file as it is thousand lines long. But it passes compilation without error, btw.

At this point I am really confusing, how can printing 0 cause error? Any hints to the source of error will be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1**:

The problem seemes to relate to Gtk library. This program has two version, one command line, the other GUI programmed in Gtk+2. Both versions use the same file that contains the above codes, but only the GUI version deliver this error.

Then it seems to be a problem related to Gtk libraries but I have no clue to debug furthur.

**Update 2**:

I tried the following two fixes

```
    fprintf(fp, "%4d %11.6f %11.6f %11.6f\n", cell->total_atom_no, 0, 0, 0.0);
    fprintf(fp, "%4d %11.6f %11.6f %11.6f\n", cell->total_atom_no, 0, 0, (float)0);
```

The error still persists.
I can print those zeros as srings without problem, but I need to know what is going wrong.

Comment: It could have something to do that you are printing integers as double-precision floating point values.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Not really. As I mentioned a simple example will give the correct results. And I never had problem printing integer using %f.

Comment: That's the thing with [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), even if it seems to work it's not correct. As for your edit, remember that the `"%f"` format in [`printf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects `double` as arguments and not `float`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right. I tried to cast all three zeros to double and the behaviour is back to normal. Thanks a lot! Can you make an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The reason is that `printf` and family expects `double` arguments for the `"%f"` format. You give it three `int` values instead.

As `int` is (normally on modern platforms) 32 bits while `double` is 64 bits, the `printf` will go outside the actual data provided to the function, and fetch seemingly random data from the stack possibly beyond its limits.

Comment: Actually the argument expected for %f is float, but can be double as well. Argument float is converted to double, so passing a float to a variadic function is completely valid.

Comment: @self. It's [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) that expects `float` for `"%f"` but [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects `double`.

Comment: float is automatically promoted to double so passing a float is considered as passing a double. 6.5.2.2(6) Making it valid.